# How to find which ajax call failed in multiple ajax call using jquery promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to make a few Ajax calls simultaneously and handle the success and failure using the ajax promise, like this

```
var j1 = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "path/to/file1",
    dataType: 'json',

    refreshSession: true
});
var j2 =  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "path/to/file2",
    dataType: 'json',

    refreshSession: true
});

$.when(j1, j2).then(function (a1, a2) {
    alert('Both j1 and j2 succeeded!');
}, function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
});
```

The params `a1` and `a2` will be an array containing the `response text`, `status`, and `jqXHR`

but in the 2nd function which is called when the request failed, how to find which request failed?

Comment: Actually it's async, edit the question.

Comment: `a2.status` should say failed right?